# How to save python script as txt?

Tags: python

I wrote this to create a new file. I want the python script that I am in to all be saved into a txt file.  What should I do next?

```
f = open("Data.txt", "x")
```

Comment: What the difference between a Python file and a text file in your opinion? The suffix? Then it should be easy, shouldn't it?

Comment: @KlausD. yes it should be jam easy but probably he is a beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this works out fine for you?
First read in the python file and save it in a variable and them simply write it out on another file.

```py
def write_python_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read()
        f.close()

    with open("Data.txt", mode="w") as f:
        f.write(data)
        f.close()

write_python_file("filename.py") # Replace with your python file.
```

Hope so this is useful information for you.